# How do I use jQuery to loop through an unspecified number of checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I need to loop through a div full of an unknown number of checkboxes and get back the values of the checkboxes that are checked, how do I do this with jQuery? I guess it should happen onchange of any of the checkboxes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do:

```
<div id="blah"> 
  <input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" />
</div>

$("#blah .mycheckbox").each(function(){
  alert(this + "is a checkbox!");
});
```

Comment: yeah that's great but how do I check which one is checked and grab the value of all the checked ones?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
<div id="blah"> 
  <input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" />
</div>

$("#blah .mycheckbox:checked").each(function(){
  alert($(this).attr("value"));
});
```

Comment: +1 I think using the selector is a better cleaner way of grabbing all that are checked within that class. If a class is not setup but a name is you can also use `$('input[name=checkboxname]:checked')` as a selector to grab all checkboxes with that name that are checked. and of course you can use `:not(:checked)` for those that are not checked, just incase you need to select those.

Answer (score 2):

```
var checkboxes = [];
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        checboxes.push($(this).val());
    }
});
```